# RequiredIf for RadioButtonFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I make RadioButton required field when textbox is not empty? I have a text box and couple of radiobuttons , 
if textbox has value I wanted make radiobutton required field.

Comment: Question is how do I force radio button if textbox not empty [RequiredIf("SomeTextBox", "what to say here" , ErrorMessage = "Message")]

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validation rules to any model in ASP.NET MVC.  Here's an example:

```
public class CoolArchTekModel : IValidatableObject {
    public string SomeTextBox { get; set; }
    public bool SomeRadioButton { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SomeTextBox) && !this.SomeRadioButton) {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The radio button is required if the text box is empty!");
        }
    }
}
```